# Error in groupby pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am running a script in windows and I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "C:\Users\esalazar\Desktop\datos\stat_cea_2011\emas\amealco\promedios-emas.py", line 64, in <module>
    g=index.groupby(level=0)    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

I have installed pandas, scipy and numpy. I need to install some other library? How do I fix this error?

This is part of my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/esalazar/Desktop/datos/stat_cea_2011/emas/amealco/enero.csv',skiprows=1,names=['Fecha','Hora','C','D','E','Temperatura','TempRocio','DirViento','I','MagViento','K','Humedad','Presion','N','PreciAcu','P','Q','R','S'],header=0)
Uviento=[]
Vviento=[]

for i in range(0,len(data['MagViento'])):
    Uviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*sin((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))
    Vviento.append((data['MagViento'][i]*cos((data['DirViento'][i]+180)*(pi/180.0))))

data['PromeU']=Uviento
data['PromeV']=Vviento

data
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
Int64Index: 4463 entries, 0 to 4462
Data columns (total 19 columns):
Fecha          4463  non-null values
Hora           4463  non-null values
C              4463  non-null values
D              4463  non-null values
E              4463  non-null values
Temperatura    4463  non-null values
TempRocio      4463  non-null values
DirViento      4463  non-null values
I              4463  non-null values
MagViento      4463  non-null values
K              4463  non-null values
Humedad        4463  non-null values
Presion        4463  non-null values
N              4463  non-null values
PreciAcu       4463  non-null values
P              4463  non-null values
Q              4463  non-null values
R              4463  non-null values
S              4463  non-null values
dtypes: float64(8), int64(4), object(7)

df = data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'],inplace=True)
df
```

i get this error

```
TypeError: NoneType object has no atribute '--getitem--'
```

therefore,

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
```

is error too.

Comment: Your `index` variable is `None`. Show the part of your code which concerns `index`.

Comment: i edit the comment whit the script that i am using

Answer (score 3):

`data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'], inplace=True)` modifies your DataFrame in place (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)); this is what `inplace=True` specifies. That is, it doesn't create a new object but rather modifies `data` directly. You can do either

```
df = data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'])
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
```

or

```
data.set_index(['Fecha','Hora'], inplace=True)
grouped = data.groupby(level=0)
```